# Is $\{3,5,6\}$ a $2\mathbb{Z}$-sequence?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I have just started reading about the concept of $M$-regular sequences on my own and to understand the definition I asked myself the following question:

> Is $\{3,5,6\}$ a $2\mathbb{Z}$-sequence?

We let $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $M=2\mathbb{Z}$.

Def: A sequence $\{a_{1},....,a_{n}\}$ of non-zero elements from $R$ is called an $M$-sequence (or $M$-regular sequence)  if

$$(a_{1},...,a_{n})M\neq M$$
and
$$a_{i}\; \text{is regular on}\; M/(a_{1},...,a_{i-1})M\; \text{for each}\; i=1,..,n$$

The first condition I think is satisfied as 
$$(3,5,6)\cdot2\mathbb{Z}=\{a\cdot3+b\cdot5+c\cdot6,\; a,b,c\in2\mathbb{Z}\}=\mathbb{Z}$$
For the second part I check if $3$ is regular on $2\mathbb{Z}$, $3m\neq 0$ for all $m$ in $2\mathbb{Z}$ unless $m=0$ so $3$ is not a zero divisor on $2\mathbb{Z}$ hence regular.

Next, I have to check if $5$ is regular on $2\mathbb{Z}/(3)2\mathbb{Z}=2\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}=\{a+(6), a\in 2\mathbb{Z}\}=\{0+(6), 2+(6), 4+(6)\}$. We have $5(a+(6))=5a+(6)\neq 0+(6)$ unless $a=0$ so $5$ is not a zero divisor on $2\mathbb{Z}/(3)$

Finally, $6$ is regular on $2\mathbb{Z}/(3\cdot5)2\mathbb{Z}=2\mathbb{Z}/30\mathbb{Z}=\{a+(30), a\in 2\mathbb{Z}\}$ but $6a+(30)=0+(30)$ if $a=5n$, $n=0,1...$ but since $a\not\in2\mathbb{Z}$ for any $n$ $6$ must be regular too, making the sequence $\{3,5,6\}$ $2\mathbb{Z}$-regular?

Am I correct? Thank you.

Comment: $6$ is not a regular element in $2\mathbb Z/30\mathbb Z$ because $6 \cdot 10 = 0$ in $2\mathbb Z/30\mathbb Z.$

Comment: I am sorry, I was doing two problems simultaneously. I have corrected the post. You are right! Say, if we exclude the last element, then the remaining two elements 3,5 produce regular sequence right? Is it  a maximal regular sequence then?

Comment: $(3,5,6)\cdot2\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb Z$? If $I$ is an ideal of $R,$ then $IM$ is a submodule of $M.$ Here you are producing something which properly contains $M$? How is this true? Am I missing something here?

Comment: You are right. The product is the whole module M, not the whole ring. Hence it violates the first assumption of the definition.

Comment: The sequence $\{3, 5 \}$ is weakly $2\mathbb Z$-regular sequence.

Comment: So only $\{3\}$ is  $2\mathbb{Z}$-regular. Is it also the maximal $2\mathbb{Z}$-sequence (in (3,5,6))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The ideal generated by 3,5 and 6 is $\mathbb{Z}$. Thus $(3,5,6) \cdot M =M$ for every $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My mistake. Then I guess it cannot be a regular sequence at all.